# Paper-Button how do you know which button has been clicked?

Tags: polymer

In the new paper-button 1.0 how do we tell which button has been clicked on? In 0.5 you inspected the element passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use getAttributes.

```
setFilter: function(e) {
               var filter = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("filter");
               console.log(filter);
               var title  = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("title");
               console.log(this.obj_filters);
```

Works a treat

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two buttons like these.

```
<paper-button id="b1" class="clickable" on-click="buttonClick">
    button1
</paper-button>
<paper-button id="b2" class="clickable" on-click="buttonClick">
    button2
</paper-button>
```

Then you can use this function to determine which one was clicked.

```
buttonClick: function (e) {
    for (var i = 0, max = e.path.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (e.path[i].classList && e.path[i].classList.contains("clickable")) {
            console.log("clicked button: " + e.path[i].id);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Better solution:

```
buttonClick: function (e) {
    console.log("clicked button: " + e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. We were going down that root also but didn't really want to start looping. So we talked to the Polymer team on Slack and @sjmiles came back with getAttributes to do the job. We now have it working :)